# Default dbo for queries

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to set the default dbo for a user(or ODBC connection)?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM [DBO].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]
```

The user can also request this query and will achieve the same results:

```
SELECT * FROM [SCHEMA].[TABLE]
```

For this case, there are other DBOs pressent(IE [DBO1], [DBO2], etc) but all(or specific users) will default its query to [DBO]. Also without using USE [] statement.

Comment: Do you *really* have a database called `dbo`? But yes, you can set the default database for a `LOGIN`, if that's what you're asking. That default, however, is only used if database is not defined in the connection string.

Comment: In general, your connection should determine the database to use for all object references. That is one reason why your tsql code should generally avoid using 3 part names (i.e., database,schema.table).  You can set a default database for each login, which will make that database the current database when a connection is established without specifying a database. But in general, your code should establish a connection to a specific database.

Comment: @Larnu No, I dont have a database named dbo, it was just for an example. So I can set a default database for a LOGIN and still be able to query from other database present?

Comment: Every `LOGIN` has a default database, @Dense04, just if you don't define one it'll be `master`. You can still query other databases, provided you have a mapped `USER` with the relevant permissions; either by connecting directly to that database in the connection string, using a `USE` statement to change the database context, or using 3 part naming for the object(s).

Comment: @SMor I believe that is not possible for our current setup. What we have right now is that in one server, we have 3 databases that we managed, DB1, DB2, DB3. DB1 contains the meta data and stored procs that we use across other databases. DB1 is used for both storage and configs while the remaining dbs are for storage only.

Comment: I agree with @SMor though, generally relying on the default settings causes more problems that it solves. Be explicit and define the database in the connection string.

Comment: One last comment. The term "dbo" means something very specific in sql server. Using it to refer to a database is very, VERY confusing. Your tsql code and your app's connection determine the current database for any 1 or 2 part object names. Seems you want some sort of dynamic redirection when a database name is include in your tsql queries - for which there is no obvious tsql feature/technique to accomplish. Perhaps a layer in your application can accomodate this.

Comment: Sorry for such confusing statement, used only the [DBO] as an example. Going forward, let's refer to those databases as [database1], [database2], [database3]. Recapping, [database1] stores the meta tables and data while the two only includes the data. The query always queries to [database1] in order to get the metadata of the specific Item i want. I.E. IDs 1-10 are in [database1] and 11-20 are in [database2] and so on. If im accessing ID 1, it will query from [database1] in order to get its metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to setup the default database for a login. By default is set to master but you can change it by issuing:

```
ALTER LOGIN [LOGIN_NAME] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME];
```

You can check current default database setting for each login using this statement:

```
SELECT loginname, dbname FROM sys.syslogins
```

Comment: I have a similar db which does what I want. I have check its properties and all the logins are defaulted to [dbo]. On the other server which I am working on, have the same properties but does not behave like the first one.What I did on my working server was, (1) manually created the dbs I need. (2) Imported the meta tables from the working server. (3) Updated user/roles. With this, I am still unable to replicate the behavior of the working server.